# Can you actually get the 5-star equipment in the banner above the Common Relic Draw through that draw?

Tags: final-fantasy-record-keeper

In the daily free "Common Relic Draw" there is a banner above that has 5-star equipment like the Masamune and Tiny Bee. Most of the other banners only advertise things you can get. I have been playing for a month or so and I have never gotten anything above 2 stars. I understand it is free so the odds are likely much lower but I figured I would have at least gotten a 3-star item by now. I was just curious if the odds are non-zero or if that banner is just kind of a weird advertisement for the event based draws?

Comment: I've been playing the game for almost 2 years now, I've gotten several 3*, a SINGLE 4* and not ONE 5*. From different forums, it appears this is pretty much the norm, as someone actually pulling a 5* in the free relic draw is considered very lucky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a good source from the [FFRK Subreddit FAQ](https://www.reddit.com/r/FFRecordKeeper/wiki/links/faq#title#faq):

> What is the chance of pulling a <5 STAR ITEM>?
>
> For a quick answer, you have ~0.001% chance of getting a specific 5* off a Common Relic draw, and about 1% to get a "featured" 5* off a Rare Relic draw. Common Relic Draws keep all released items, so the chance for a 5* item off of Common Relic Draw is 0.001 * the number of 5* equipment that can be pulled (a total chance of 0.034% at the time of this edit). Rare Relic Draw banners currently have a 10% chance of dropping a 5* item.

Basically, common draws *could* pull a 5* item, but they're so freaking rare that you're better off buying a lottery ticket in most cases.

The [numbers linked](https://www.reddit.com/r/FFRecordKeeper/comments/33g3mn/relic_draw_item_drop_rates_provided_by/) are somewhat out of date (as more items have been added over time), but they seem to indicate around 73% chance of pulling a 1*, a 20% chance of 2*, a 6% chance for 3*, a tenth of a percent for 4*, and a hundredth of a percent for a 5*.

Answer (score 1):

I've pulled a 3-star from the Common Relic draw, but not yet a 5-star.  I think those items ARE available, but without the boosted drop rate the event Relic Draws usually have, they are exceedingly rare.

The same thing happens with the Half Price x11 Draws, to the point I've stopped throwing away Mythril on them because I've not gotten a 5-star from them yet.  I'll save my Mythril for an Event draw with an item I want.

Comment: I've actually not seen a difference in 5* drop rate between the regular 11X for 50 mythril draws or the half priced draws.

Comment: @CoqPwner During an event advertising boosted drop rates, I typically get between 2 and 4  5-stars from a x11 draw.  Across my admittedly small sample of three half-price draws, I've failed to get a single 5-star.  It's hard to get a decent sample size since the half-price draws are once only.  It *could* be just my bad luck, but I think the lack of the "boosted drop rate" language that's always on the event draws indicates your chances are lower.

Comment: I think thats just bad luck by you.  The last one I got 2 5*.

Answer (score 1):

I was pretty sure it's impossible to get 5-6 star pull from the daily draw until yesterday. Over 3 years and I haven't missed many days and now I finally got one. Today I pulled another one. Feels like something might have changed. [image][image]

Answer (score 0):

I personally have pulled 2, 5 star relics from the common relic draw almost a year ago, both were the brotherhood sword, so if you do get a 5 star, chances are it isn't going to be an amazing 5 star.